# How to make a live-chat with AJAX without making tons of requests ( 100 / Minute )

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, chat

**Hello** everyone, i'm currently working on a live chat ( For fun ) and i found **ajax**. It allows me to refresh the chat ( With request every second ) without refreshing the page.
Everything is fine but there are **too many requests** ( 60 - 100 / Minutes ) and i would like to **reduce** this.

I searched for solution and found **Long-Polling** but didn't understand it ( At least **didn't understand** how to **implement it** into my code )
I also foud **socket.io** but i want to **stay in php.**

Here is my Js / Jquery code :

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($){


refreshMessages()
document.getElementById("send").focus();

$("#submit").on("click",function(e){

    e.preventDefault();

    var user = <?php echo json_encode($user); ?>;
    var token = user["token"];
    var username = user["username"];
    var message = $("#send").val();
    var file = $("#file").val();

    $('#send').val(null)

    $.ajax({ 
    url : 'add.php',
    type : 'POST',
    data : {"token" : token, "username" : username,"content" : message,"file" : file},
    
    success : function(data){
        
    },

    error : function(){
    }
    });
    setTimeout(updateScroll2,200)
})

function updateScroll(){
    document.getElementById("scroll_chat").scrollTop = document.getElementById("scroll_chat").scrollHeight;
}

function updateScroll2(){
    document.getElementById("scroll_chat").scrollTop = document.getElementById("scroll_chat").scrollHeight;
}


setTimeout(updateScroll,170)

function refreshMessages() {

    $.ajax({
        url: 'get.php',
        type: 'GET',
        dataType: 'html',
        success: function(data) {
            
        $('#scroll_chat').html(data); // data came back ok, so display it
        setTimeout(refreshMessages, 5000);
        },
        error: function() {
        $('#scroll_chat').prepend('Erreur');
        }
    });

}
```

});

*add.php* is trigerred when the message form is submitted and it simply inserts the message ( Date , Content , Author and token ) in my database

*get.php* is a SELECT * query to my database and it echoes in a foreach loop every messages.

So i have an Ajax get request emitted every second and that's too much, anyone has an idea about it ?

Best regards stackOverflowers,
Nano

Comment: LONG poll is the server holds open the http request for a long time. WebSockets is the way to go for chat applications. There are websocket frameworks out there for php

Comment: @osekmedia did you read the question? lol

Comment: Have you looked into web sockets using PHP with Ratchet?

Comment: recommend websocket here too. try to search sockjs, stomp

Comment: Thanks jejun but i need a php app, not nodeJS ^^

Comment: Osekmedia and epascarello, thanks a lot.
I'm currently trying to implement websockets via Ratchet ( A php websocket framework ) in my app but it's on the right way ;)